# How to make docker container in macOS accessable in local network like a physical computer?

Tags: macos, docker

I use Docker Desktop in macOS. I have an Ubuntu container running in docker. I want to access my Ubuntu container from other computers in the local network as if the docker container itself is a physical computer.

Something like in VirtualBox, if I change network to "bridged adapter" and bridge it to my network adapter. e.g. My physical computer has IP address 192.168.1.100, my virtual machine has IP address 192.168.1.101, another computer in the local network which has the IP address 192.168.1.102 can access the virtual machine using IP address 192.168.1.101.

Is it possible in docker macOS version? As far as I know I cannot use macvlan network in macOS. And I don't want port forwarding.